# Roslyn. Add assembly reference to project

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm trying to add assembly reference to my project via Roslyn. What I have

```
    static void UpdateProjects(string soluiton, string assemblyPath)
    {

        var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
        var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(soluiton).Result;
        var rewrittenSolution = solution;
        var projectIds = rewrittenSolution.ProjectIds;
        for (int i = 0; i < projectIds.Count; i++)
        {
            var addedRef = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assemblyPath)
                    .WithProperties(new MetadataReferenceProperties(MetadataImageKind.Assembly));

            rewrittenSolution = rewrittenSolution.AddMetadataReference(projectIds[i], addedRef);
            workspace.TryApplyChanges(rewrittenSolution);
        }
    }
```

And it doesn't work. When I do TryApplyChanges, there error System.NullReferenceException in Roslyn.
What I do wrong?

```
Stack Trace:
System.NullReferenceException
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.ProjectFile.AddMetadataReference(MetadataReference reference, AssemblyIdentity identity)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.ApplyMetadataReferenceAdded(ProjectId projectId, MetadataReference metadataReference)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.ApplyProjectChanges(ProjectChanges projectChanges)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.ApplyProjectChanges(ProjectChanges projectChanges)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution, IProgressTracker progressTracker)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution, IProgressTracker progressTracker)
   at RoslynTestApp.Program.UpdateProjects(String soluiton, String assemblyPath)
   at RoslynTestApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks Added stack trace

Comment: The code is failing somewhere in this method: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild/MSBuild/ProjectFile/ProjectFile.cs,292